# Putting values from array into text boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an JSON array that looks like this:

```
{class: "local", coverage: "inclusive", day: "1", week: "2", month: "3"}
{class: "local", coverage: "alt", day: "4", week: "5", month: "6"}
{class: "travel", coverage: "inclusive", day: "7", week: "8", month: "9"}
{class: "travel", coverage: "alt", day: "10", week: "11", month: "12"}
{class: "suv", coverage: "inclusive", day: "13", week: "14", month: "15"}
{class: "suv", coverage: "alt", day: "16", week: "17", month: "18"}
{class: "minivan", coverage: "inclusive", day: "19", week: "20", month: "21"}
{class: "minivan", coverage: "alt", day: "22", week: "23", month: "24"}
{class: "convert", coverage: "inclusive", day: "25", week: "26", month: "27"}
{class: "convert", coverage: "alt", day: "28", week: "29", month: "30"}
```

And I need to get the values for each day and put them in the corresponding text boxes that are laid out like this:

```
document.getElementById(cstartdate + "-" + cenddate + "-" + city + "-local-inclusive-day").value = "";
document.getElementById(cstartdate + "-" + cenddate + "-" + city + "-local-alt-day").value = "";
```

So according to the array the first line needs to equal "1" an the second line needs to equal "2"

A better way of saying this would be

```
document.getElementById(cstartdate + "-" + cenddate + "-" + city + "-local-inclusive-day").value needs to equal {class: "local", coverage: "inclusive", day: "1"
```

Etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: How are you computing `cstartdate` and `cenddate`? and what value do you want to write?

Comment: that ^,  and what's the difference between `"alt"` and "`inclusive`"?

Comment: cstartdate and cenddate are being passed into the function, and the difference between "alt" and "inclusive" is is they are two different values.

Comment: Where there first line is needs to be "1" and the second line needs to be "2", if that makes sense.

Comment: what denotes the difference between each one? do you just need multiple elements created as they go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const json = require("path-to-your-json");
// OR const json = JSON.parse(your json array)
const setValue = (cstartdate, cenddate, city, obj) => {
  const target = document.getElementById(cstartdate + "-" + cenddate + "-" + city + "-local-" + obj.coverage +"-day");
  target.innerText = obj.day;
}

json.forEach((obj) => setValue(cstartdate, cenddate, city, obj))
```

Comment: not exactly but thanks for your efforts, I did it a much sloppier way and just decided to leave it.